# Laravel Route-Model binding doesn't work if route is defined in route group

Tags: php, laravel

i have this route,

```
Route::get('/posts/show/{post}', 'PostsController@show');

//corresponding controller method
public function show(Post $post){
  //method logic
}
```

this works perfectly when route is defined outside of Route::group.

But this fails;

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{user}.localhost.com'], function () {
...
    Route::get('/posts/show/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
...
}
```

Erro Output;

```
 Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::show() must be an instance of App\Post, string given
```

To see what was being passed as parameter, i modified the PostsController::show() to below;

```
public function show($post){
    return $post;
}

//it returned the subdomain part of the url.
```

I can safely say route group is working as intended because i have other routes and they work. (as long as they don't use Route-Model binding ofc)

i have found 2 other posts addressing the same issue but they didn't helped me with this.

Comment: `public function show($user, Post $post){` ?

Comment: You are capturing two parameters (wrapped in braces) but only made room for one.

Comment: yes! it worked. 1 question, why? btw thanks

Comment: @Devon what do you mean capturing two? this is my first time dealing with subdomains so please ignore if i sound uninformed

Comment: @thatoneguy doing `['domain' => '{user}.localhost.com']` means the `{user}` becomes a parameter like `$user` and `'/posts/show/{post}'` also becomes `$post`. So your controller would accept both the `$user` and the `$post` but the `$user` is the first parameter which is a string and you are passing `Post` instead. So make the `$user` the first parameter and `Post $post` the second

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have created a subdomain wildcard route which accepts one parameter which is the `{user}` and inside your route group you are accepting another parameter which is the `{post}` if you want to use route model binding, arrange the parameters in the appropriate order. example `$user`,`$post`

So your controller should look like

```
public function show($user,Post $post){
  //method logic
}
```