# Laravel controller cannot inject type-hinted model

Tags: laravel, controller

It looks very simple but I cannot solve this weird problem more than 3 hours..;;

I just create my controller method like

```
// AccountTeacherPassportController.php
public function delete(Teacher $teacher)
{
    // do things
}
```

to use this method, I wrote route..

```
Route::post('deltp/{teacher}', 'AccountTeacherPassportController@delete')->name('delTeacherPassport');
```

It is super simple situation and I get this error..

Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Administrators\AccountTeacherPassportController::delete() must be an instance of App\Gatesplan\Teacher\Teacher, string given

Someone who experience like this, help me out.. lol

---

Solved. Following is my problem report.

source : [Laravel Route-Model binding doesn't work if route is defined in route group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161325/laravel-route-model-binding-doesnt-work-if-route-is-defined-in-route-group)

### Something that might you need

1. Injecting model into route parameter, you cannot choose one from url `{wildcard}`s.
2. You must provide wildcard object "in order".
3. You don't need to use all wildcard as long as you following 2.

---

My problem was that, the entry point url using two wildcard `{user}`, `{teacher}` but my controller method accept only one paramter `public function delete(Teacher $teacher)` which is not ordered. So I modify the method like `public function delete($user, Teacher $teacher)` and works. Obviously, `public function delete(User $user, Teacher $teacher) also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding) while you are using `explicit binding`

> To register an explicit binding, use the router's model method to specify the class for a given parameter. You should define your explicit model bindings in the boot method of the `RouteServiceProvider` class:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('teacher', App\Gatesplan\Teacher\Teacher::class);
}
```

> Next, define a route that contains a {teacher} parameter (you already did)

```
Route::post('deltp/{teacher}', 'AccountTeacherPassportController@delete')->name('delTeacherPassport');
```

Comment: Ok now I know what is the problem. However, this is the first time that explicit model binding and I already use route param frequently. Is some model dont have to bind manually?